# Is this absolute value inequality correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification, absolute-value

Given $ -3 - x \lt  x - 4 \lt -3 + x $, I want to add absolute value bracket to $x - 4$,  making it $ |x - 4| \lt a $.

$\because|x - 4| < a$ means $  -a \lt x - 4 \lt a . $

$ \because-(- 3- x) > (-3 + x) $

$ \therefore -3 -x \lt x - 4\lt -3 + x \lt 3+ x$

$ \therefore |x - 4| < 3+ x $

Is this correct?

Comment: No it is not since you have on RHS $-3+x$. If it would be $3+x$ then would be ok.

Comment: Would this be right if x>0.

Answer (score 1):

Given $$ -3 - x \lt  x - 4 \lt -3 + x $$
you can add  $3$ to all sides and get
$$ - x \lt  x - 1 \lt + x $$
hence
$$|x-1| \lt x.$$

The solution is $x>1/2. $

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$-3 - x \lt  x - 4 \iff x> \frac12$$

$$x - 4 \lt -3 + x \iff -4<-3$$

therefore

$$|x - 4| \ge 0 $$

Comment: AFAIK $|x-4|$ is greater than or equal to zero for each real $x$, but the inequalities given are not satisfied e.g. by $x=-7$.